# Verification of sudoing password by a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sudo

I'm writing a BASH script that interactively asks the user for the sudoing password. This should happen just once when the script is run. Before proceeding, the script needs to make sure that the password is valid.

What would be the simplest way to verify that password?

Comment: What's it doing, because that sounds well, wrong. I'd expect the script to be marked up as requiring su, or to drop out if it didn't have the required privileges.

Comment: **Do Not Do This**, it's a horrible security risk. If your `su` or `sudo` allow this, they are _severely_ broken. Use one of the keystores that are around (e.g. `seahorse` for Gnome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use the `-v` Validation Flag

You can validate credentials with sudo using the `-v` flag, and then inspect sudo's exit status. For example:

```
if sudo -v; then
    echo "Exit status: $?"
    echo "You're validated."
else
    echo "Exit status: $?"
    echo "You've failed to validate."
fi
```

Comment: @DesmondHume Sudo will ask the user for their password. To ask a user for their password and to store it yourself is a security concern, actually if I saw a programmer do that I would probably chastise them. You need to just issue sudo and let it pass on to them and let it cache itself as sudo does automatically.